# Understanding photodiode modes and practical effect on noise vs response time tradeoffs for audio applications

Tags: audio, photodiode, rise-time

I am an experimental musician with admittedly very little electronics experience (but I do have a mathematics degree) trying to find a decent photodiode for a project where I send audio signals via laser, potentially with another medium in between (such as ink or paint in water, or smoke) to color the sound.

My first goal is to simply get a clean signal through air using a laser and a photodiode. My initial prototype using cheap parts had some success, but it also had a lot of noise, even when operated in a completely dark environment.

I have read that many/most photodiodes roughly have two modes - one where some reverse bias is applied and which has faster response times but higher dark current and another where no reverse bias is applied that produces voltage via photoconductivity with lower dark current but also slower response times.

On a practical level, what should I consider when picking my photodiode with regards to this trade off? The datasheets I've read only specify the rise times at a given reverse bias voltage, at nothing when used purely photoconductivity. Should I worry more about dark current impacting noise or slow rise times clipping the detail frequency range of an audio signal? And is there any place one can easily evaluate directly how the continuum of reverse bias voltages effect dark current and rise times for a typical photodiode?

Comment: Surface area maybe, if you are aiming a laser at it across a room.

Comment: Are you saying that you will be intentionally mode-mixing and dispersing your laser beam before it is received by a detector? If so, I'm perhaps more worried about a modulation scheme and appropriate receiver optics to survive the process than I am a "decent photodiode." But you know your application better than I do.

Comment: @BrianDrummond not across a room. More like a few inches very likely, no more than a foot.

Comment: @jonk For starters, no. My first priority is getting a clean signal through just air. I understand that more forethought may be needed for the end goal, but I gotta learn this stuff the hard way - and I feel I might discover some neat things in doing so.

But your point is well taken and I've chosen to edit the original post to clarify that goal.

Comment: Well, using a digital scheme would probably be easiest but obviously prohibits any optical modulation. The same is true for frequency modulation schemes. However, but if you use amplitude modulation you can probably easily filter out some noise and still get some optical modulations (at least attenuation). Can you elaborate on your current design?

Comment: @michi7x7 Literally the simplest design possible, as I am a total beginner.

Laptop connected to audio interface, audio routed through it -> aux cord out of headphone jack connected directly to laser (using ground and only one channel) with volume cranked pretty high.

Photodiode connected to another aux chord in similar fashion, aux chord into other laptop via mic port.

Recording a software-generated tone in receiving laptop plays correct pitch but distorted. Song test was rhythmic noise, though I could distinguish the high hat.

Comment: @robert, well you may at least want to look into the simplest amplitude modulation schemes - which basically work by periodically (~100kHz) switching the signal on/off.

Comment: A PIN photodiode in photo-voltaic mode has been used (with fairly modest optics) to transmit audio thru air & very dark environment **more than 100km** with both VIS laser source and high-power LED source. Audio bandwidth was limited to hundreds of Hz. You might do better in a bright environment with a simpler photoconductive PIN detector diode in a transimpedance circuit.